# Adobe Premiere Pro 6 "sorry, incompatible sampling-frequency" error

Tags: adobe-premiere

I'm trying to edit a video using Adobe Premiere Pro 6. I tried fixing an audio clip by applying the denoiser effect. After that I keep getting the error "sorry, incompatible sampling-frequency" whenever I move on the timeline or open the project. If I turn off the track that the clip is on, the error goes away. I have removed the effect from the clip but the error persists.

I tried editing the .prproj file with a text editor to manually remove the denoiser reference. That fixes the original problem but now I get the error "Audio Filter missing:" on open. There's one additional reference in the proj file "1095781938 DeNoiser2&" inside the `<WorkspaceSettings <WorkspaceDefinition>` tag. I have no idea how to interpret what to remove though. Anyone have some insights?

Answer (score -1):

I found an ugly brute force solution. If you add a new track, move all the files from the problem track to this new track and then delete the problem track the "sorry, incompatible sampling-frequency" error goes away. Somehow the Denoiser effect has a remnant saved to the track that results in the error.